# install Xap file to nokia lumia 520

Tags: jquery-mobile, cordova, xap, lumia

Currently working mobile development based on jquery mobile and phoneGap.i can build run in android and iPhone device. it working fine. but the problem is i cannot install xap files to windows phone. i don't have SDK for windows phone.There is any third party tool to deploy xap and install to windows phone.

Comment: you can get XapDeploy.exe upon installing SDK.Why don't you install SDK?

Comment: @vits working in devExpress tool to develop application. its not require SDK.